# Changing An Objects Variables by Another's Variables

Tags: c#, xna

I'm coding a game in XNA and I have two subclasses (Character and Enemy). I wanted to create a method that would lower an enemy's health by the character attack score. How would I do that? I'm having issues with having classes interact with each other.

Would it be possible to do something similar to a constructor, where I could type in something like:

```
Attack(player.attack, enemy.health);
```

And if the player's attack score was 2, and the enemies health was 10, after invoking the method the enemy would have 8 health left.

Answer (score 1):

Probably cleaner to make `Attack` a method on the enemy class, then you can `Attack` the enemy using your player:

```
enemy.Attack(player);
```

The code in the `Attack` method on the enemy will look at the player.attack property, and decrement its own health accordingly.

Comment: One of the issues with my game (it's turn based) is that I have a int called `turnOrder` that is supposed to control who gets to hit when. I can't make it static because it's supposed to change every time an action performed.

Comment: @Dumpcats: I think we might need to know a bit more about the game design to help you. For turn-based games, I've typically had a lot of success using the State Design Pattern, to manage transitions between turns / states of play, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You might consider splitting this up a little. Example:

```
// Method on each player, which in turn calls the method below.
// This is called when myPlayer attacks enemyPlayer.
myPlayer.AttackPlayer(enemyPlayer); 


// Called from within the AttackPlayer method which was called on
// myPlayer. The parameter <damage> is a (private?) property in myPlayer:
enemyPlayer.ReceiveAttack(damage);
```

This should make it fairly clear what is happening, and let you handle different aspects in a flexible way, in case you might want to expand this later.

Example: The player receiving the attack might behave differently in different situation (eg. receive less damage if he has armour, etc), without the attacker having to take this into consideration.